# PHP Get Row's Timestamp AFTER saving

Tags: php, mysql

i knew that you can get the unique id of a row after saving by using the insert_id. my question is can i also get the actual timestamp value of a row on mysql database right after saving?

Comment: Visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657206/mysql-how-can-i-get-the-timestamp-of-the-last-insertion-to-the-database or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364430/timestamp-for-row-creation-and-last-modification?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> question is can i also get the actual timestamp value of a row on mysql database right after saving

Sure. Once you got ID of that row you just `SELECT` it and you will get all the data you need.

Comment: yup, i have thought of that, im just wondering if there's any quick way of doing that. thanks for validating my first guess.

Comment: @kapitan sure. Just type faster.